# How to access specific object from a query collection in RubyOnrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am new to rubyonrails. Right now working for a Shopify project. I have retrived a collection from one of my table and I could not able to print any specific field values in view.

My Query in controller (its a helper method).

```
def getcustomoptions product_id
  customoptions = Productoption.where(product_id: product_id).first
  return ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(customoptions)
end

helper_method :getcustomoptions
```

And in my view, When I debug the output in view,

```
pdtoption = getcustomoptions(option.id)
debug pdtoption
```

is

```
{"id":3,"product_id":10647391438,"front_preview":"tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/front_previews/000/000/003/original/collar-green-front.png?1496132797","left_side_preview":"tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/left_side_previews/000/000/003/original/t-shirt-left-side.jpg?1496132798","back_preview":"tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/back_previews/000/000/003/original/collar-green-back.png?1496132798","right_side_preview":"tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/right_side_previews/000/000/003/original/tshirt-brightlights-side.jpg?1496132798","front_preview_file_name":"collar-green-front.png","front_preview_content_type":"image/png","front_preview_file_size":275338,"front_preview_updated_at":"2017-05-30T08:26:37.864Z","left_side_preview_file_name":"t-shirt-left-side.jpg","left_side_preview_content_type":"image/jpeg","left_side_preview_file_size":79742,"left_side_preview_updated_at":"2017-05-30T08:26:38.280Z","back_preview_file_name":"collar-green-back.png","back_preview_content_type":"image/png","back_preview_file_size":250070,"back_preview_updated_at":"2017-05-30T08:26:38.437Z","right_side_preview_file_name":"tshirt-brightlights-side.jpg","right_side_preview_content_type":"image/jpeg","right_side_preview_file_size":56997,"right_side_preview_updated_at":"2017-05-30T08:26:38.618Z"}
```

And while I decode the result in view,

```
pdtoption = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(getcustomoptions(option.id))
debug pdtoption
```

is

```
{"id"=>3, "product_id"=>10647391438, "front_preview"=>"tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/front_previews/000/000/003/original/collar-green-front.png?1496132797", "left_side_preview"=>"tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/left_side_previews/000/000/003/original/t-shirt-left-side.jpg?1496132798", "back_preview"=>"tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/back_previews/000/000/003/original/collar-green-back.png?1496132798", "right_side_preview"=>"tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/right_side_previews/000/000/003/original/tshirt-brightlights-side.jpg?1496132798", "front_preview_file_name"=>"collar-green-front.png", "front_preview_content_type"=>"image/png", "front_preview_file_size"=>275338, "front_preview_updated_at"=>"2017-05-30T08:26:37.864Z", "left_side_preview_file_name"=>"t-shirt-left-side.jpg", "left_side_preview_content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "left_side_preview_file_size"=>79742, "left_side_preview_updated_at"=>"2017-05-30T08:26:38.280Z", "back_preview_file_name"=>"collar-green-back.png", "back_preview_content_type"=>"image/png", "back_preview_file_size"=>250070, "back_preview_updated_at"=>"2017-05-30T08:26:38.437Z", "right_side_preview_file_name"=>"tshirt-brightlights-side.jpg", "right_side_preview_content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "right_side_preview_file_size"=>56997, "right_side_preview_updated_at"=>"2017-05-30T08:26:38.618Z"}
```

But I could not able to print/display a specific value (eg: front_preview). I am struggling with this for more than 3 hours, but could not find a proper way to handle this situation. Any help/detailed explaination is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: do `pdtoption['front_preview']`

Comment: How are you accessing values inside the hash? Can you post example code of your view where it is not working?

Comment: Hi, my view. I tried this,

`code`  
<%
  pdtoption = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(getcustomoptions(option.id))
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= pdtoption['front_view'] %></td>
    </tr>
  `code`
It throws ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: pdtoption is `nil`

Comment: No, when I debug the variable it prints all the values...

Comment: does it throw error on this exact line? what do you get for `pdtoption.class`?

Comment: Please paste your complete code, not missing anything out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am running a loop with database collection. So, It returns,

Hash for first record and NilClass for next record. Now I am trying to print it by using some conditions, It's not working. 

`<%= (pdtoption.class == 'Hash' ? pdtoption['front_preview'] : '-') %>`

In PHP the error will be thrown only in the second loop of the statement, Where as here it doesn't allow to print the output for first loop itself.

Comment: My view file
`<% @productoptions.each do |option| 
        attrbs = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(getcustomizationattr(option.id))
        customizable = ''
        
        attrbs.each do |attri| 
         customizable = attri["value"]
        end  
    if(customizable == 'enable')  
        inc += 1;
        pdtoption = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(getcustomoptions(option.id))
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= option.title %></td>
    <td><%= pdtoption.class %> <%= (pdtoption.class == 'Hash' ? pdtoption['front_preview'] : '-') %></td>
    </tr>
    <% 
    end
    end %>`

Comment: Identified the issue with my ternary operation. The right-hand side class name "hash" have to be compared without quotes. 

`<%= (pdtoption.class == Hash ? pdtoption['front_preview'] : '-') %>` 

I know it's not the proper way to check whether an object is empty or not but for now it's working. 

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: you can do `pdtoption.is_a?(Hash)`

Answer (score 0):

If you closely look at the `ActiveSupport::Json.decode` method, it parses your Json-String and returns a [Ruby Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html). To access data of the Hash `pdtoption` you need to use the normal Ruby hash accessor methods.

```
pdtoption["id"] #=> 3
```

To pass data from your controllers to the view, you don't need to encode and decode the data everytime. You could just return your `customoptions` in your helper method and access it in the view.

Comment: When I directly use the query output it seem like this,

--- !ruby/object:Productoption
concise_attributes:
- !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: id
  value_before_type_cast: 3
- !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: product_id
  value_before_type_cast: 10647391438
- !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: front_preview
  value_before_type_cast: collar-green-front.png

But could not find a way to display the column value.